# Vue-storefront-api problem (Error on homepage)

Tags: api, vue.js, vue-storefront

I have set up vue-storefront on https://hoversport.no/.

- Though it's not showing the standard homepage layout as there's an
  error, most definitely with the API.
- I have no output errors in terminal, everything is running OK, no
  servers such as node etc are trying to run on same ports, absolutely
  everything I get is Green OK/Running.
- Either it's something in the config, permissions or something else I
  can't wrap my head around.

Not sure where to look and where to start, how to solve this issue.

Expected results should be like this: https://demo.mage-pwa.io/

Any help is truly appreciated!

**This is the vue-storefront/config files** 
https://github.com/Decntdefalt/vue-storefront-config

**This is the vue-storefront-api/config file** 
https://github.com/Decntdefalt/vue-storefront-api-config

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: You need to show us the code that connects to your API and also any queries that are run.

Comment: I've edited the original post and included repositories for the config files that I'm using. Thing is, I'm not getting any errors in the output, so I'm not sure what errors to look for when I don't see them.. the only error I'm aware of is on the homepage itself https://hoversport.no/

Answer (score 1):

according to the configs it seems that your node app (vue storefront api) was not correctly configured in your nginx. https://hoversport.no/api/catalog should return a response and currently it doesn't.

What is missing here is nginx config mentioned at:
https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront/blob/master/docs/guide/installation/production-setup.md#nginx

and if it's correctly pointed, you should navigate to your vue-storefront-api folder and run:
`node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 logs` to investigate the remaining issues with api node app.